# How to call a resource in a service through a controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-services, angular-controller

I want to send the data in my controller to the database via service, but I use a $resource in a service and I don't know how to call it from the controller, below is my controller,

```
 angular.module('dashboard').controller('DashboardCtrl',['dashboardResource',DashboardCtrl]);

    function DashboardCtrl(dashboardResource){
     var vm = this;

        vm.payments = [
            {
                "paymentId":1,
                "date":"2015/09/13 12.36PM",
                "name":"HSBC Bank",
                "ID": 123456,
                "amount": 1000.00,
                "status": "Active"
            }]
 vm.payments = dashboardResource.get({name: vm.payments.name}, function(payments) {

          payments = vm.payments();
      });
    }
```

Below is my service

```
angular.module('lgpsService').factory('dashboardResource',[
        "$resource",dashboardResource]);

    function dashboardResource($resource) {
        return $resource('api/Payment/makePayment');
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the issue? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: You need to handle the $promise, but would be helpful to explain your problem more in detail

Comment: I want to send data to the db but there's an error saying that "GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/Payment/makePayment 404 (Not Found)" but the path is right.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to send the data in my controller to the database via service

I am not sure if you want to post or get data or here via factory resource. I am going to answer to have both the methods. You can call it via controller in following way and you need to make some changes in service as well.

Your service will be like below

```
     var app = angular.module('lgpsService').factory('dashboardResource',[
               "$resource",dashboardResource]);

     app.factory('dashboardResource', function($resource) {
             return $resource(
                     'api/Payment/makePayment',
                     {},
                     {
                        'post' {
                             method: 'POST' //To post data
                         },
                         'get' {
                             method: 'GET' //To get data
                          }
                     }
                 );
             });
```

Your controller

```js
angular.module('dashboard',['lgpsService']).controller('DashboardCtrl',['dashboardResource',DashboardCtrl]);

    function DashboardCtrl(dashboardResource){
     var vm = this;

        vm.payments = [
            {
                "paymentId":1,
                "date":"2015/09/13 12.36PM",
                "name":"HSBC Bank",
                "ID": 123456,
                "amount": 1000.00,
                "status": "Active"
            }]

          //Call service to post data
          dashboardResource.post( vm.payments                                 
                    function(){
                        console.log('data saved successfully');
                    },
                    function(error){
                        AlertService.add( "Error saving data " + error.data);
                        
                    }         
          )
          
          //Call service to get data
         
           dashboardResource.get().
            $then(
                  function(response) {
                    //Do your stuff with data here
                    console.log( response.data );
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
```

Hope this helps to you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to mention `ngResource` as a dependency in your `lgpsService` like this

```
angular.module('lgpsService',['ngResource'])
       .factory('dashboardResource',['$resource',dashboardResource]);
```

Also you need to `angular-resource.js` to your HTML page after `angular.js`.

As your `dashboardResource` factory is in a different module `lgpsService`, you need to mention that module as a dependency in your main module like this

```
angular.module('dashboard',['lgpsService'])
       .controller('DashboardCtrl',['dashboardResource',DashboardCtrl]);
```

Change your controller function to call `save()` on your resource object which in turn will make a POST request to that URI.

```
function DashboardCtrl(dashboardResource){
     var vm = this;

        vm.payments = [
            {
                "paymentId":1,
                "date":"2015/09/13 12.36PM",
                "name":"HSBC Bank",
                "ID": 123456,
                "amount": 1000.00,
                "status": "Active"
            }]
   var payments = dashboardResource.save({name: vm.payments.name}, 
        function() {
             /*success callback. By this time `payments` object is augmented
             with the response from your POST call */
             vm.payments = payments;
      });
}
```

Another important thing to note is that the return type of any method get/save from $resource is promise object and also it has all the fields copied from the original HTTP response.